# How to symbolize "The most likely value of the sum of a bunch of things is the sum of the most likely values of each of the things"?

Tags: probability

Kindly see the boldened sentence below. What probability concept does "the most likely value" refer to? How do I symbolize it?

I don't think the author's referring to Expected Value, because it's additive.

> The principle of additivity is so intuitively appealing that it’s easy to think
> it’s obvious. But, just like the pricing of life annuities, it’s not obvious! To see
> that, substitute other notions in place of expected value and watch everything
> go haywire. Consider:
>       ***The most likely value of the sum of a bunch of things is the sum of the
> most likely values of each of the things.*** [emphasis mine]
>       That’s totally wrong. Suppose I choose randomly which of my three
> children to give the family fortune to. The most likely value of each child’s
> share is zero, because there’s a two in three chance I’m disinheriting them.
> But the most likely value of the sum of those three allotments—in fact, its
> *only possible* value—is the amount of my whole estate.

Ellenberg, *How Not to Be Wrong* (2014), page 213.

Comment: the point that maximizes the density, i guess?

Comment: Where is the confusion?  If you have a list of possible values with various (unequal) probabilities, the most likely value is the one with the greatest probability.

Comment: For another numerical example, suppose you have a loaded die which comes up $1$ with probability $\frac 16+\epsilon$, and takes all the other values with probability $\frac 16-\frac {\epsilon}5$, for very small $\epsilon$.  Then of course the most likely value is $1$.  But the most likely value of the sum of two rolls is still $7$, not $2$.

Comment: The writer's heuristic sort of holds true for **independent** random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to describe a situation in which $\operatorname{mode}(X_1 + \cdots +X_n) = \operatorname{mode} X_1 + \cdots + \operatorname{mode} X_n$.

Comment: But, to be clear,  mode can have multiple values...

Comment: Absolutely, just trying to put in symbols what I think the original post was saying. Whether it makes sense or not is a different thing. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can only really define the “most likely” value for some random variable. If $f$ is a pdf for a random $X,$ then the most like value of $X$ is the “mode” of $X,$ a value $x_0$ such that:

$$f(x_0)=\sup_x f(x).$$

But the mode is not necessarily unique. And even if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a unique mode, $X_1+X_2$ might not.

I suppose, if $f$ is continuous, you could define $M_f=\sup_x f(x),$ then define, for $M<M_f,$ $E_{f,M} =\{x\mid f(x)>M\}$ and define our “most like value” as:

$$\begin{align}\mathcal A(X)&=\lim_{M\to {M_f}^-}\frac{\int_{E_{f,M}}xf(x)\,dx}{\int_{E_{f,M}}f(x)\,dx} \\&=\lim_{M\to {M_{f}}^{-}}E\left(X\mid X\in E_{f,M}\right)\end{align}$$

That will be, roughly, a weighted average when there are multiple values for the mode, where the weights prefer the ones where $f$ converges more slowly to $\sup f.$ In particular, if there is one mode, $A(X)$ will be that mode.

This definition satisfies some useful rules.

$\mathcal A(aX+b)=a\mathcal A(X)+b$ when $a,b$ are (constant) real numbers.

If $X$ is a an even distribution ($f(x)=f(-x)$) then $\mathcal A(X)=E(X)=0.$

This definition works for some $f$ unbounded, for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ in $(0,1].$ Then $M\to +\infty.$

If  $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are real continuous random variables, then we would want:

$$\mathcal A(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)=\mathcal A(X_1)+\mathcal A(X_2)+\cdots +\mathcal A(X_n).$$

This is true if the $X_i$ are normal, or more generally if $X_i-E(X_i)$ is even.

But this won’t be true in general.

Comment: Thanks! My 10 year old and I will need to re-read your post, after we learn calculus LOL.